# Shopping basket script in object-oriented PHP

Tags: beginner, php, object-oriented, e-commerce

I have made a shopping basket script that allows the user to add and remove items from the basket, and edit quantity of items that are in the basket.

I am new to OOP, and I would like to get your feedback on it about whether I am doing it well. The whole script works but I need to know if it could be improved or it is fine.

```
<?php

Class Item{

  public $db, $item_id, $result, $image, $title, $description, $stock, $price, $salePrice, $isFreeDelivery, $deliveryPrice;

  function __construct($db_connection, $item_id){
    $this->db = $db_connection;
    $this->item_id = $item_id;

    try{

      $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = :item_id LIMIT 1"); 
      $stmt->bindParam(':item_id', $this->item_id);
      $stmt->execute();

    }catch(PDOException $e) {

      echo $e->getMessage();

    }    

    $this->result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $this->image = $this->getImage();
    $this->title = $this->getTitle();
    $this->description = $this->getDescription();
    $this->stock = $this->getStock();
    $this->price = $this->getPrice();
    $this->salePrice = $this->getSalePrice();
    $this->isFreeDelivery = $this->isFreeDelivery();
    $this->deliveryPrice = $this->getDeliveryPrice();


  }

  function getImage(){

    foreach($this->result as $row){
      return $row["image"];
    }

  }

  function getTitle(){

    foreach($this->result as $row){
      return $row["title"];
    }

  }

  function getDescription(){

    foreach($this->result as $row){
      return $row["description"];
    }

  }

  function getStock(){

    foreach($this->result as $row){
      return $row["quantity"];
    }

  }

  function getPrice(){

    foreach($this->result as $row){
      return $row["price"];
    }

  }

  function getSalePrice(){

    foreach($this->result as $row){
      return $row["salePrice"];
    }

  }

  function getAmountSaved(){
    return "&pound;".($this->getPrice()-$this->getSalePrice());
  }

  function getPercentageOff(){
    return round($this->getSalePrice() / $this->getPrice() * 100)."%";
  }

  function isFreeDelivery(){

    foreach($this->result as $row){
      return $row["freeDelivery"];
    }

  }

  function getDeliveryPrice(){

    foreach($this->result as $row){
      return $row["deliveryPrice"];
    }

  }

}

?>
```

class.basket.php

```
<?php

Class Basket{

  public $db, $user_id, $item_id = array(), $itemsInBasket = 0;

  function __construct($db_connection, $user_id){
      $this->db = $db_connection;
      $this->user_id = $user_id;
  }


  function basketCount(){

    try{

      $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE userid = :user_id LIMIT 1"); 
      $stmt->bindParam(':user_id', $this->user_id);
      $stmt->execute();

    }catch(PDOException $e) {

      echo $e->getMessage();

    }    

    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    foreach($result as $row){
      return $row["itemsBasket"];
    }

  }

  function countItemNo($item_id){ //returns quantity in basket of a single product

    try{

      $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM basket WHERE item_id = :item_id AND user_id = :user_id LIMIT 1"); 
      $stmt->bindParam(':item_id', $item_id);
      $stmt->bindParam(':user_id', $this->user_id);
      $stmt->execute();

    }catch(PDOException $e) {

      echo $e->getMessage();

    }    

    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    foreach($result as $row){
      return $row["quantity"];
    }

  }

  function isInBasket($item_id){

    try{

      $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM basket WHERE item_id = :item_id AND user_id = :user_id LIMIT 1"); 
      $stmt->bindParam(':item_id', $item_id);
      $stmt->bindParam(':user_id', $this->user_id);
      $stmt->execute();

    }catch(PDOException $e) {

      echo $e->getMessage();

    }   



    $numRows = $stmt->rowCount();

    if ($numRows == 1){
      return true;
    }else{
      return false;
    }


  }

  function addToBasket($item_id, $quantity){

    //add to user basket count and to basket table
    //add number of product to add
    //check if in basket to increase

    if ($this->isInBasket($item_id) == false){

      try{

        $stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO `storify`.`basket` (`id`, `item_id`, `quantity`, `user_id`) VALUES (NULL, :item_id, :quantity, :user_id)"); 
        $stmt->bindParam(':item_id', $item_id);
        $stmt->bindParam(':quantity', $quantity);
        $stmt->bindParam(':user_id', $this->user_id);
        $stmt->execute();

      }catch(PDOException $e) {

        echo $e->getMessage();

      }

    }else{


      try{

        $stmt = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE `storify`.`basket` SET quantity = quantity + :quantity WHERE item_id = :item_id AND user_id = :user_id LIMIT 1"); 
        $stmt->bindParam(':item_id', $item_id);
        $stmt->bindParam(':quantity', $quantity);
        $stmt->bindParam(':user_id', $this->user_id);
        $stmt->execute();

      }catch(PDOException $e) {

        echo $e->getMessage();

      }

    }


    try{

      $stmt = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE `storify`.`tbl_users` SET itemsBasket = itemsBasket + :quantity WHERE userid = :user_id"); 
      $stmt->bindParam(':quantity', $quantity);
      $stmt->bindParam(':user_id', $this->user_id);
      $stmt->execute();

    }catch(PDOException $e) {

      echo $e->getMessage();

    }      


  }

  function removeFromBasket($item_id){ //remove all of an item from basket

    //get quantity in basket
    //decrease that quantity in user table
    //remove item basket row from basket table

    $quantityInBasket = $this->countItemNo($item_id);


    try{

      $stmt = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE `storify`.`tbl_users` SET itemsBasket = itemsBasket - :quantity WHERE userid = :user_id"); 
      $stmt->bindParam(':quantity', $quantityInBasket);
      $stmt->bindParam(':user_id', $this->user_id);
      $stmt->execute();

    }catch(PDOException $e) {

      echo $e->getMessage();

    } 

    try{

      $stmt = $this->db->prepare("DELETE FROM basket WHERE item_id = :item_id AND user_id = :user_id"); 
      $stmt->bindParam(':item_id', $item_id);
      $stmt->bindParam(':user_id', $this->user_id);
      $stmt->execute();

    }catch(PDOException $e) {

      echo $e->getMessage();

    } 


  }

  function editBasketQuantity($item_id, $new_quantity){

    //get quanity in basket
    //check that there are still at least one left - if not, run removeFromBasket($item_id);

    try{

      $stmt = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE basket SET quantity = :new_quantity WHERE item_id = :item_id AND user_id = :user_id"); 
      $stmt->bindParam(':new_quantity', $new_quantity);
      $stmt->bindParam(':user_id', $this->user_id);
      $stmt->bindParam(':item_id', $item_id);
      $stmt->execute();

    }catch(PDOException $e) {

      echo $e->getMessage();

    } 



  }



  function selectAllFromBasket(){

    try{

      $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM basket WHERE user_id = :user_id");
      $stmt->bindParam(':user_id', $this->user_id);
      $stmt->execute();

    }catch(PDOException $e) {

      echo $e->getMessage();

    }

    if ($stmt->rowCount() != 0){

      $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

      foreach ($result as $row){

        $this->itemsInBasket++;

        $this->item_id[] = $row['item_id'];

      }

    }else{
      echo "<p style='font-family: arial;'>No items in basket</p>";
    }




  }




}

?>
```

And finally here is basket.php

```
<?php

include_once "includes/header.php";
require_once "classes/class.db.php";
require_once "classes/class.item.php";
require_once "classes/class.user.php";
require_once "classes/class.basket.php";


if (User::logged_in() != false){

    $basket = new Basket($db, $_SESSION['user_id']);

    //prints out containers and title
    echo "
    <div id='itemInfoNegative' style='width: 610px; padding: 5px;'></div>
    <div id='itemInfoPositive' style='width: 610px; padding: 5px;'></div>
    <div id='inBasketContainer'>
    <h3>In Basket</h3>";

    $basket->selectAllFromBasket();

    for ($i = 0; $i < $basket->itemsInBasket; $i++) { //loops through items in basket

        $item_id = $basket->item_id[$i];
        $item = new Item($db, $item_id);

        echo "<div class='item'>
        <img src='".$item->getImage()."'/>
        <p class='itemTitle'><a href='item.php?item_id=$item_id'>".$item->getTitle()."</a></p><br>";

        if ($item->getStock() >= $basket->countItemNo($item_id)){
            echo "<p class='inBasketInStock'>In Stock</p>";
        }else if ($item->getStock() == 0){
            echo "<p class='inBasketLowStock'>Out of Stock</p>";
        }else{
            echo "<p class='inBasketLowStock'>Only ".$item->getStock()." left in stock</p>";
        }

        echo "
        <form method='post' class='deleteFromBasketForm'>
        <input type='hidden' name='item_id' value='$item_id' />
        <input type='submit' class='deleteFromBasket_$item_id' class='deleteFromBasket' value='Remove'/>
        </form>
        <br>
        <p class='deleteFromBasketLink' onClick='removeFromBasketClick($item_id)'>Remove</p>

        <select class='selectQuantity' onchange='getval(this);'>";

        for ($x = 1; $x <= $item->getStock(); $x++){

            if ($x == $basket->countItemNo($item_id)){
                echo "<option selected='selected' value='$x'>$x</option>";
            }else{
                echo "<option value='$x'>$x</option>";
            }

        }

        echo "</select>
        </div>"; //ends .item container

    } 

    echo "</div>"; //ends .inBasketContainer container

}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the item class you don't really need functions to get each part of the item unless you intend on making all of those functions public so other classes/files may use them.

You use a foreach loop in each of the functions but the select in the construct method will only ever return 1 result (LIMIT 1 in the query). No need for looping.

```
$this->result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$row = $this->result[0];  // first and only record in the array

$this->image = $row['image'];
$this->title = $row['title'];
```

etc ... notice also that I used single quotes around image instead of double quotes. There is no reason to have PHP determine whether or not that is a variable or a constant. In this case, and for the column names for the other items, it is always going to be a constant.

You do something similar in your basket class and that could be updated as shown above (unless there are methods there that you want available to other classes/files).